# How to display JSON data from API?

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, codable

I am developing in Swift 4 and currently using Walmart's API in order to display their products and certain information about the products (example: name of product, price of product). I have read and watched many tutorials regarding parsing JSON data however I continue to get the same error. If anyone could tell me why im getting an error it would be highly appreciated seeing I have been stuck on this issue for days.

Here is the JSON data I am getting from the API call:

```
{
query: "ipod",
sort: "relevance",
format: "json",
responseGroup: "base",
totalResults: 3570,
start: 1,
numItems: 10,
items: [
{
    itemId: 15076191,
    parentItemId: 15076191,
    name: "Apple iPod Touch 4th Generation 32GB with Bonus Accessory Kit",
    salePrice: 189
 }
```

I just want to display the `name` and `salePrice` data but I am unable to do so at the moment, instead I get this error: `typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Here is my data model:

```
  struct Product: Codable {
    let name: String
    let salePrice: String

}
```

Here is the code in my ViewController class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


import Foundation
import UIKit    


var products: [Product]?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let urlString = "http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/search?query=sauce&format=json&apiKey=xyz"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }

        guard let data = data else { return }
        //Implement JSON decoding and parsing
        do {
            //Decode retrived data with JSONDecoder and assing type of Article object
            let productData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: data)
            print(productData)

        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }

    }.resume()



}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json data is a dictionary not an array you either parse it and get the array , or try this

```
struct Item: Codable {
   let query: String
   let sort: String
   let format: String
   let responseGroup: String
   let totalResults: Int
   let start: Int
   let numItems: Int
   let items: [Product]

}

struct Product: Codable {
   let itemId: Double 
   let parentItemId: Double 
   let name: String
   let salePrice: Int

}

let productData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: data)
```

Comment: I just tried code and received the same error as before.

Comment: wait edit ........

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

It will be like this,

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let query: String
    let sort: String
    let responseGroup: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let start: Int
    let numItems: Int
    let items: [Product]
}

struct Product: Codable {
    let name: String
    let salePrice: CGFloat
}
```

Try using this,

```
let productData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Item.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Upvoted.

Comment: :( you don't have enough reputation to upvote so sad

Comment: I will do it :)

Comment: @Sh_Khan thank you so much